# How to generate a list of lines from a text file in PyScript?

Tags: python, html, pyscript

Reads lines from a text file, py-script, HTML
Need to generate list of lines from a text file in pyscript

```
async def process_file(event):
    fileList = event.target.files.to_py()

    for f in fileList:
        file_in= await f.text()
                #This code does not generate a set of lines, but generate only a continuous string
                # The output needs to be like file.readlines() in Python.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's built-in [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split the full input into a list of lines, by splitting on the newline character `\n`.

```py
# ...
file_in = await f.text()
lines = file_in.split('\n')

# Do something with individual lines:
for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    print(f"Line {index}: {line}")
```